# How to calculate the quadratic variation of this martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

In a larger proof I'm stuck on finding the quadratic variation of the martingale given by
$$M_n = X_n-Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n1_{A_k} - P(A_k\vert \mathcal F_{k-1}),$$
where $A_k\in\mathcal F_k$.
I already have that $M_n$ is a martingale. Further, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
E(M_n^2)&=E\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n1_{A_k}-P(A_k\vert\mathcal F_{k-1})\right)^2\right) \\
&\le E\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n1_{A_k}\right)^2\right)\\
&\le E\left((n1_{\cup A_k})^2\right)=n^2E(1_{\cup_{k=1}^nA_k})\\
&= n^2P(\cup_{k=1}^n A_k)<\infty,
\end{aligned}$$
which (unless I made an error) shows that the quadratic variation in fact exists. However when I plug the martingale in to the formula for the quadratic variation, I'm stuck on
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle M_n\rangle 
&= \sum_{j=1}^n E((M_j-M_{j-1})^2\vert \mathcal F_{j-1})\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n E\left(\left(1_{A_j}-P(A_j\vert\mathcal F_{j-1})\right)^2\vert \mathcal F_{j-1}\right)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n E\left(1_{A_j}-2P(A_j\vert\mathcal F_{j-1})1_{A_j}+P^2(A_j\vert\mathcal F_{j-1})\vert\mathcal F_{j-1}\right)\\
\end{aligned}.$$
I'm sure I'm just overlooking something, but I can't simplify this thing further. But perhaps there is a better way of finding the quadratic variation that I don't know of?

EDIT: I noticed $P(A_j\vert\mathcal F_{j-1})$ is a constant, but I'm not exactly sure (how) I'm allowed to pull it out.

Comment: Hint: $\mathsf{E}[1_{A_j}-2\mathsf{P}(A_j|\mathscr{F}_{j-1})1_{A_j} + \mathsf{P}^2(A_j|\mathscr{F}_{j-1})|\mathscr{F}_{j-1}]
= \mathsf{P}(A_j|\mathscr{F}_{j-1})-\mathsf{P}^2(A_j|\mathscr{F}_{j-1}) $

Comment: @JGWang am I seeing this correctly: $E(1_{A_j}\vert \mathcal F_{j-1}) = P(A_j\vert\mathcal F_{j-1})$ and I'm allowed to just take the $P(A_j\vert\mathcal F_{j-1})$-terms out?

Comment: $\mathsf{P}^2(A_j|\mathscr{F}_{j-1})$ is $\mathscr{F}_{j-1} $-measurable, hence 
$ \mathsf{E}[\mathsf{P}^2(A_j|\mathscr{F}_{j-1})|\mathscr{F}_{j-1}] = \mathsf{P}^2(A_j|\mathscr{F}_{j-1}) $ too.